# how can i fix this kubernetes plugin in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I have  problem with Jenkins
but Jenkins  is  connecting  by  my Kubernetes by  this credentials`mykubeconfig`
but its  show to me this error

ERROR: ERROR: Cannot find kubeconfig credentials with id mykubeconfig

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find kubeconfig credentials with id mykubeconfig

https://pasteboard.co/J2PGyNr.png

https://pasteboard.co/J2PGLEi.png

https://pasteboard.co/J2PGYKH.png
https://pasteboard.co/J2PH8ye.png

Comment: you have checked in your jenkins credentials available with respective config value to connect to k8s ?

Comment: could you please share a screen shot of your jenkins credentials page?

Answer (score 1):

When you're using Jenkins Kubernetes Deployment plugin, you have to create two credentials.

1. Kind -> Secret file. Here you have to provide your kube config file. It'll be    used in Cloud -> Kubernetes section to connect to Kubernetes cluster.
2. Kind -> Kubernetes configuration(kubeconfig). Here you've to paste your kube config content or set path of kube config file. **This need to be called in pipeline** as `kubeconfigId`.